# Multiple references to same sitecolumn in a content type

Tags: site-column

I have a content page with well defined placeholders (10 of them). I want to control the HTML that sorrounds them, so I have to use 10 instances of them.

Do I have to create 10 different site columns; such as banner1, banner2,..., banner10? Or is there an easier solution?

Comment: Does this mean you will be able to include up to 10 different banners ? Or do you have one banner always on the same location just with different content. Something like snippets you like to reuse?